# rclone does not fit screen when using --progress with --transfers 400

Tags: rclone

How do I make rclone just show transferred and elapsed time, as showing everything that is transferred at --transfers 400 does not fit the screen anymore and bugs out, especially when under the `screen` Terminal command.